# Morning nausea after Chemo

Tags: cancer, prevention, stomach, chemotherapy, anti-nausea

I am 22, and my mom is 59.  So, my mom got diagnosed with breast cancer back in 2005, and took radiation and chemotherapy in late 2005/2006.  Anyway, she's doing well now except for red-green color blindness and she has nausea pretty much every morning.  She, of course, takes nausea pills (Promethazine) and drinks Ginger Tea.  Yes, the ginger tea helps it go away, but then it comes back the next morning persistently.  I just don't know a way to prevent it from happening in the first place?   Is there any thing I should be looking into to help?  Any remedies or anything that helped anyone in a similar situation?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should be looking into getting help.

Nausea during chemotherapy is very common, and should be treated. But nausea in the morning 9 years after chemotherapy? That is not at all normal.

There are a great many medical problems [that can cause nausea](http://www.mayoclinic.org/symptoms/nausea/basics/causes/sym-20050736), including, unfortunately, a possible recurrence of her cancer. These should be ruled out by her doctor(s) as soon as possible.

While you are waiting to see the doctor, you mentioned, ginger is a natural anti-emetic (anti-nausea). Ginger tea, ginger ale and even candied ginger can help. Eating 5-6 smaller meals, rather than 3 large meals, helps, as does keeping plain crackers by the bedside and eating some as soon as she wakes up (before rising), and rice or toast at night.

Comment: Yeah she pretty much does what you have mentioned, a few small means and ginger (tea, ale, candy, actual ginger root), also milk makes it worse I believe.  She does have toast at night and crackers every now and again.  It doesn't have to do with a relapse at this point, I believe that has been ruled out.   These things help it go away most of the time (though they can take a while) after the nausea occurs but I was sort of looking for a way to get at completely preventing the morning nausea?  I just thought there was some medication or remedy I haven't hear of in this modern day.

Comment: At least in America, many ginger ales don't contain real ginger, at least in any listed amount. I've found those less effective. I use a product that is only ginger juice with a bit of honey and lemon to make it taste better, I find it works as well as ginger tea. Drinking it regularly can be preventative, and, since it's in the fridge, it's easily accessible, especially if I'm not up to making tea. This is an anecdote, not a study, so I hope you don't mind me mentioning it.

Comment: Not at all. Any suggestions for which product you use?